# Facebook login redirect issue

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, symfony, facebook-login

I have a site with a working Facebook login.

The problem is happens when the user comes to the site for the first time (or after clearing cookies).

The user flow is the following:

1. User clicks "Sign Up with Facebook"
2. User is redirected to Facebook authentication
3. If User accepts, he/she is redirected to the 'Sign Up' page.

The problem is that **if the person is doing this for the first time, they are always redirected back to the home page**.

There are only 2 possible views that can be given for this url

1. The Sign Up page, with only some form data sent as parameters
2. An alert box upon successful DB persistence

Thus, I have ruled out PHP as a possible cause of the redirect.

I have included the JavaScript managing the Facebook interaction.

All other relevant code can be found in the HTML of the page.

The Page can be found at http://trioisrael.com

```
function fb_login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {
            window.location = "http://trioisrael.com/signup"
            //console.log(response); // dump complete info
            access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                user_email = response.email; //get user email
                // you can store this data into your database
            });

        } else {
            //user hit cancel button
            alert('We use facebook to make sure that everyone is really who they say they are');

        }
    }, {
        scope: 'user_photos,user_birthday'
    });
}
```

Comment: Trying to do additional stuff after assigning a new value to window.location (which should be window.location.href, of course) does not make sense.

Comment: @CBroe - I'm not trying to do anything after a redirect.  Facebook authenticates on their server and then sends back some encrypted user data.  Then my page checks that they are logged in and allows them to continue with the form.  The problem is that they are not immediately recognized as being signed in on the first attempt.  They get redirected to the home page, click the link and are authorized.

Comment: Of course you are trying to do so, because you have further code following your window.location line.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, that solved it.  Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to do additional stuff after assigning a new value to `window.location` (which should be `window.location.href`, of course) does not make sense.

If you want to do additional stuff after login, do it *before* redirecting the user somewhere else.